# CSV - Only keep certain entries

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk, csv

I have a bunch of data inside `""` and separated by `,` - Example below of two lines

```
"stampthisandthat.com","GANDI SAS","3fdb1bcc220148658e7ea1a96aef1585-1184687@contact.gandi.net","whois.gandi.net","A.DNS.GANDI.NET|B.DNS.GANDI.NET|C.DNS.GANDI.NET|","16-feb-2012","28-feb-2013","16-feb-2014","2012-02-16 00:00:00 UTC","2013-02-28 00:00:00 UTC","2014-02-16 00:00:00 UTC","clientTransferProhibited","2013-11-12 08:00:00 UTC","3fdb1bcc220148658e7ea1a96aef1585-1184687@contact.gandi.net","Laura VOGT","","Gandi, 63-65 boulevard Massena","","","","(Gandi) Paris","","(Gandi) 75013","(Gandi) FR","33143730576","","33170377666","","3fdb1bcc220148658e7ea1a96aef1585-1184687@contact.gandi.net","Laura VOGT","","Gandi, 63-65 boulevard Massena","","","","(Gandi) Paris","","(Gandi) 75013","(Gandi) FR","33143730576","","33170377666",""|
"salochinbd.com","FASTDOMAIN, INC.","nick.bekeris@gmail.com","whois.fastdomain.com","NS1.IPAGE.COM|NS2.IPAGE.COM|","17-feb-2012","03-feb-2013","17-feb-2014","2012-02-17 00:00:00 UTC","2013-02-03 00:00:00 UTC","2014-02-17 00:00:00 UTC","ok","2013-11-12 08:00:00 UTC","nick.bekeris@gmail.com","","","","","","","Cedar Rapids","Iowa","52402","UNITED STATES","","","13192100679","","nick.bekeris@gmail.com","","","","","","","Cedar Rapids","Iowa","52402","UNITED STATES","","","13192100679",""|
```

How would I go about keeping only certain data? For example, how can I keep only the data inside the first, second and fifth `""`.

Comment: When asking this type of questions please post an example of desired/expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cut -d\" -f2,4,10 <in | tr \" , >out
```

...would grab only the quoted bits for fields 1,2 and 5 and afterward ensure they get separated w/ commas.

Or, since it appears some commas can occur within the quotes...

```
 cut -d\" -f-5,10-11 <in | sed s/,$// >out
```

...or even...

```
cut -d\" -f-5,10 <in | paste -d\" - /dev/null >out
```

...might set that to rights.

The first prints:

```
stampthisandthat.com,GANDI SAS,A.DNS.GANDI.NET|B.DNS.GANDI.NET|C.DNS.GANDI.NET|
salochinbd.com,FASTDOMAIN, INC.,NS1.IPAGE.COM|NS2.IPAGE.COM|
```

...and the second, third...

```
"stampthisandthat.com","GANDI SAS","A.DNS.GANDI.NET|B.DNS.GANDI.NET|C.DNS.GANDI.NET|"
"salochinbd.com","FASTDOMAIN, INC.","NS1.IPAGE.COM|NS2.IPAGE.COM|"
```

Here is an example demonstrating how to do similar for fields 1,3,17,21,22,23,24 :

```
printf '"%s"\n' "$(seq -s\",\" 35)" |
cut -d\" -f-3,6-7,34-35,42-48       |
paste -d\" - /dev/null
```

---

```
"1","3","17","21","22","23","24"
```

...which pulls only those fields out a `seq` output which looks like:

```
"1","2","3",..."35"
```

Comment: How does the columns work? I can't figure out how 5,10-11 = that data. All the columns I need currently are 1,3,17,21,22,23,24 (based off the awk command below)

Comment: @Teddy291 - the fields are split on `"`. The first field is a null field - because the first character is `"`. Field 2 is everything between the first and second `"` and `cut` prints it led by a `"`, 3 is `","`, 4 is `"GANDI SAS"`, and 5 is `",'` again. The 10th field is `"A.DNS...`, which, if printed without the 11th doesn't get a `"` appended, but if printed w/ it, gets `",` appended - which is why we either append a `"` w/ `paste` and drop field 11, or we include it and strip the trailing `,` w/ `sed`. `cut` - if it works - is almost definitely the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There's a little-known program named [csvquote](https://github.com/dbro/csvquote) that makes it possible to use standard tools like `cut`, `sed`, and `awk` to handle CSV files.  It works by mapping special characters inside quotes to some unprintable characters, and then mapping them back.  With this program, it's as simple as this:

```
csvquote file.csv | cut -d , -f 1,2,5 | csvquote -u
```

Output:

```
"stampthisandthat.com","GANDI SAS","A.DNS.GANDI.NET|B.DNS.GANDI.NET|C.DNS.GANDI.NET|"
"salochinbd.com","FASTDOMAIN, INC.","NS1.IPAGE.COM|NS2.IPAGE.COM|"
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk -F',' '{print $1 $2 $5}'` - Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for me as some of the data has , in the fields. How else could I do it using awk?

Answer (score 0):

To get around your issue with included commas in the fields, change your field separator to **quote+comma**; assuming that your included commas in the fields are not at the very beginning and/or end of the field.

```
$ awk -F'(\",)' '{print $1 $2 $17}' test.txt
```

Just make sure you *escape* the quote and surround field separator in single quotes to protect from your shell.

**NOTE** This is on Fedora 20 using `gawk`, I believe.